# Why do my single-jumps sometimes count as double-jumps?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

As a Scout using the Baby Face's Blaster, I need to conserve my double jumps for when I really need them. Now, sometimes, I've noticed that, when I do a single jump off the edge of a ledge, that jump is counted as a double-jump (the reason I know this is that my Boost meter drops when this happens).

Why is this, and in what other situations does a single-jump count as a double-jump?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that this is happening because you fall off the ledge slightly just before you press the jump button. This would cause it to be a double jump because you are jumping while falling/in the air even though you only pressed the jump button once.

Comment: Yes, any jump you make while in the air counts as a double-jump.